# php DOM read from webpage

Tags: php, html, dom

I am new to `php` DOM, I read about [**`DOMDocument`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). I am trying to create `DOMDocument` from a webpage. So, that I can perform `DOM` operations on the loaded webpage.

I tried this,

```
<?php
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTMLFile("www.google.com");
    echo($dom->textContent);
?>
```

I tried several functions like, `load`,`loadHTML`...

Later I want to perform operations like, `getElementById()` etc..

How can I do that.?

Comment: So our code isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile` can open just files in local system. So you should download it first.

```
<php
    $dom = loadHtmlFromWeb("www.google.com");
    echo($dom->textContent);

    /**
     * @param string $url
     *  
     * @return DOMDocument
     */
    function loadHtmlFromWeb($url) {
         $curl = curl_init() ) {
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
         $out = curl_exec($curl);
         curl_close($curl);

         $dom = new DOMDocument();
         if (!empty($out)) {
             $dom->loadHTML($out );
         }
         return $dom;
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an actual URL: `$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.google.com/");`